# Separate in-ear mixes for 2 instruments

Tags: mixing

I would like to mix instruments and a backing track to send to musicians' in-ear monitors, but we want different mixes for each output. We want a device that does something like the following schematic.

[image]

We have found that mixers tend to mix everything into the same channel, but we would like different mixes for each output channel. We found some solutions but they are devices that have way more inputs than we need, and of course way out of budget.

My current idea is two split the signal 2 ways and get 2 4 channel mixers but I would like to avoid dealing with such a messy setup while going from place to place.

Thanks!

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is auxiliary send bus (commonly called aux send). You need a mixer with at least one aux send per dedicated in-ear mix.